# AngularJS ui-route prevent changing a state until finished http call

Tags: angularjs

I have this state that allows a user to select a "sport". When they select a sport a http call is made to pull in all garments by that sport, the function looks like this:

```
set: function (sport) {

    // Update our service
    service.sports.sport = sport;
    service.kits.kit.team.sport = sport.slug;

    // Update our garments
    service.garments.list().then(function () {

        // Save our session
        service.saveSession();
    });
},
```

The problem is, that the user "could" potentially try to navigate to the next child state. I have a validation function set up as a **resolve** to make sure the user has filed all the required fields in before progressing to the next state, it looks like this:

```
validateTeam: function () {

    // If we have no colours selected or the team name has not been set or we have no sport
    if (!service.kits.kit.colour1 || !service.kits.kit.colour2 || !service.kits.kit.team.name || !service.kits.kit.team.sport || $http.pendingRequests.length > 0) {

        // Timeout to trigger digest
        $timeout(function () {

            // Redirect to the first state
            $state.go('designer.team');

            // If no sport has been set
            if (!service.kits.kit.team.sport) {

                // Display a warning
                toastr.warning('You must choose a sport.');
            }

            // If no team name has been set
            if (!service.kits.kit.team.name) {

                // Display a warning
                toastr.warning('You have not entered your team name.');
            }

            // If no colours have been chosen
            if (!service.kits.kit.colour1 || !service.kits.kit.colour2) {

                // Display a warning
                toastr.warning('You must select at least 2 colours.');
            }
        });
    }
},
```

As you can see, I have added a line that doesn't display an error, but does change state:

```
$http.pendingRequests.length > 0
```

So basically, if there are any http requests, it redirects back to the team state (the first state).

This works, but doesn't do exactly what I would like. For a start, sometimes it flashes the next state before it redrects, but the main issue is that if I am on a child state (after all validation has passed) and I refresh the page, it will **always** take me back to the **team** state because there are other http requests going on.

Does anyone know of a clean way to navigate to the next state **after** the set sport http request has completed **if** a state change has been requested?

Comment: provide a snippet where you call `validateTeam()`

Answer (score 1):

An event called `$stateChangeStart` will be broadcast when starting a state change. You can catch the event and prevent the state change if it meets certain condition.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
        if(isCallingApi)
            event.preventDefault(); 
    })
```

`isCallingApi` is just a simple boolean to keep track if you are calling API.